MPEG2-TS relate packet timestamp to video frame timestamp
I have a recording encoded as MPEG2-TS (audio and video). I have an absolute timestamping of each 188-byte packet: I known when each packet was encoded and stored.
My problem is now how to relate relative time information (DTS or PTS) of each frame (video only) to absolute time of each packet. I can extract each frame info by means of ffprobe:
ffprobe -select_streams v -show_frames MyRecording.ts

Is there any straightforward way to link frame-to-packet timestamping (or even frame-to-packet indices)?
